# How can I stop render() function till all the state will be updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below will call render() function three times. Is there a way to wait till all the three properties in state will be updated and then call render() only once?
Maybe I should use shouldComponentUpdate? I'm new to ReactJS. I don't know how it would look like.
Any ideas?

```
import React from "react";

export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      first: "value1",
      second: "value2",
      third: "value3"
    };
  }

  changeFirst() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ first: "somethingFirst" });
    }, 2000);
  }
  changeSecond() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ second: "somethingSecond" });
    }, 3500);
  }
  changeThird() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ third: "somethingThird" });
    }, 5000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeFirst();
    this.changeSecond();
    this.changeThird();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state.first) +
          "\n" +
          console.log(this.state.second) +
          "\n" +
          console.log(this.state.third) +
          "\n"}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to stop the updates in the first place?  You are basically asking React to stop doing the very thing it's good at.

Comment: Let's say that I would have ten functions like this updated every second. Would it be all right when render() function is called ten times every second?

Comment: Yep, that would be absolutely fine, even though it probably indicates that your code should be refactored.

Comment: or add code in your render that it does not output that until all conditions are met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use [shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    const { first, second, third } = this.state;
    if(first !== nextState.first && second !== nextState.second && third !== nextState.third){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

this will prevent the component from updating unless the three state entires are updated.

Comment: It works but only with one condition so I decided to write the last one (third).  With 3 conditions the last value is not changed. I think it something with async of setState method. But anyway you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply exit from the render function until all three variables are set:

```
import React from "react";

export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            first: "",
            second: "",
            third: ""
        };
    }

    changeFirst() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ first: "somethingFirst" });
        }, 2000);
    }
    changeSecond() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ second: "somethingSecond" });
        }, 3500);
    }
    changeThird() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ third: "somethingThird" });
        }, 5000);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeFirst();
        this.changeSecond();
        this.changeThird();
    }

    render() {
        if (!first || !second || !third) return (<div> Loading the vars... </div>)
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this.state.first) +
                    "\n" +
                    console.log(this.state.second) +
                    "\n" +
                    console.log(this.state.third) +
                    "\n"}{" "}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```